# Delete dots and number of a page in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

In order to hide the Bibliography word I am using

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliographie}
\chapter*{Bibliographie}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
```

The problem is that is the table of contents I have dots and the number of the corresponding page in the table of contents.

How can I delete those dots and the number of the corresponding page in the table of contents?

Thanks

Comment: What does `\bibname` have anything to do with a table of contents?  Please provide a complete working example that shows the issue.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: This is what i am using,                                             
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}\begin{document}\tableofcontents\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliographie}
\chapter*{Bibliographie}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}

Comment: Rather than post this as a comment, you can edit your question and add that content directly to the question.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes, i edited my post

Answer (score 0):

There are no dots in your example, but to remove the page number:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliographie}
\chapter*{Bibliographie}
\addtocontents{toc}{{\bfseries Bibliographie}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```